# Overlay UI elements in a layout.xml using FrameView android

Tags: android, layout, view, android-edittext

I have added a text box to my mail.xml layout. I also have a surface view used for drawing to game. I'm trying to use a FrameView to overlay to text box from the main.xml layout over the SurfaceView but I a null error.

My on create, all works fine until I call "f.addView(text);"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    iso = new Iso(30,30, this);

    FrameLayout f = new FrameLayout(this);
    f.addView(iso);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    f.addView(text);

    setContentView(f);
}
```

my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

And I end up with a null pointer exception, if I take out the line "f.addView(text)" it will work fine, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot inflate your xml layout.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   iso = new Iso(30,30, this);

   FrameLayout f = new FrameLayout(this);
   f.addView(iso);

   View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, f);
   text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
   f.addView(text);

   setContentView(f);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but I get the error saying that the the requested child already has a parent and I must call removeView() first but I can't find what to do or where to do it

Comment: fixed with: 
  ((ViewGroup)text.getParent()).removeView(text);